# What pipe should I use for a short gas line for a stove in a tight area?

Tags: kitchens, natural-gas, stove, csst

I am going from an electric stove to a gas stove and I need some advice on installing the gas line.  I have a gas line running underneath the stove and there is plug where I can attach the gas line under the floor.  I was thinking about running a flexible gas line from the T to a termination plate in the floor with a value and then an excess flow valve and from there a line to the stove.

I have run black pipe before but it will be difficult to run it from the T to the floor so I was hoping to be able to use flexible line.  I was thinking csst but I only need around 3 feet and the smallest I have seen it sold in is 50 feet.  Is there another option?  Could the same type of line that feeds the stove from the value be used in this situation? Thanks.

Comment: Not a plumber. But I believe using the flex line through the floor is a code violation. You also need a gas cock (shutoff valve) at the point of use. Depending on jurisdiction, the shutoff valve might be required to be accessible without moving the stove (e.g. the gas pipe terminates in an adjacent cabinet where the shut off valve lives). Bottom line is you need to figure out your local code. Be careful with CSST. CSST is banned in some major cities like NY and also requires extra ground bonding. Also, let us know if you have natural gas or propane (sometimes called LP or LPG).

Comment: It is natural gas.  Code here states that the shutoff must be within 6 feet of the appliance.  Having it behind the stove is permitted.  That is what I was planning on.  Above the floor I have figured out.  I just need a connection from my gas line to a termination plate in the floor.

Comment: Be aware that CSST installation often requires certification. It's a trickier business than screwing black iron together.

Answer (score 1):

In my other home in MA the plumber installed CSST through the floor. As far as getting a shorter length, look at HD, but even a local supply store. I cannot imagine they wont sell you a few feet, even at some jacked up price.

Don't put flex pipe through the floor, that's not allowed (anywhere) to my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Home Depot lists [CSST ½" pipe at 25'](http://www.homedepot.com/p/1-2-in-x-25-ft-CSST-Corrugated-Stainless-Steel-Tubing-11-00525/203073939).

Lowes has a lot [shorter flex pipe](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Whirlpool-Gas-Range-Connector-Kit/1000127087?cm_mmc=SCE_PLA_ONLY-_-Appliances-_-SosAccessories-_-1000127087:Whirlpool&CAWELAID=&kpid=1000127087&CAGPSPN=pla&k_clickID=f51e0c81-3b74-48ae-b2be-854d0fc9b9e1&gclid=CjwKCAjwuITNBRBFEiwA9N9YEIW1mokzeVyux1WHn9O_25MGLHgJuRrNWAFvIxlAdJ49e-zBHC5jnBoCY68QAvD_BwE).

I don't know why you couldn't put the flex through the floor and then have your shut off valve.

I don't know what you mean by an "excess flow valve" but I would just pipe it straight through with the shut off valve in there somewhere.

Comment: An excess flow valve is a new thing added to the main black iron for example to flex pipe valves, its a part of the valve, and will "auto shut off" (its basically a check valve) and closes when the flow is unobstructed

Comment: @noybman thanks for the info. Sounds like a good idea.

Comment: Do they sell those by themselves?  I couldn't find them unless they were part of a flex pipe.